# Firecracker with Nomad or Vagrant?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualization, nomad, firecracker

I have to configure firecracker on ubuntu server.
I am little bit confuse like it should be installed standalone ( https://medium.com/@s8sg/quick-start-with-firecracker-and-firectl-in-ubuntu-f58aeedae04b ) ? **OR** inside any orchestration tools like vagrant or nomad?
If yes what will be better option?